# Laravel uploaded file not appears in linked "public/storage" folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I run command: `php artisan storage:link`, this creates folder `/public/storage`.

then I have code, which handles uploaded file:

```
// get file original name and extension here, then generate file new name $fileNameToStore
// set file path
$path = $request->file('my_file')->storeAs('public/uploaded_imgs', $fileNameToStore);
```

Code works and uploaded file appears in `/storage/app/public/uploaded_imgs/` folder, which is nice, though there is nothing in    `/public/storage` folder.

Why there is not `uploaded_imgs` folder in `/public/storage` directory?  What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you running this in a VM by any chance?

Comment: how did you create a /public/storage dir?

Comment: @mikrafizik - Laravel comes with `/public` folder, then wen I run `php artisan storage:link`, this creates `storage` folder into `/public`

Comment: @lagbox - No, this is not VM, (BTW I'm on ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: I think it might depends on your file expolerer and way of processing with sym links - in some caseses I've noticed results simply cache.

Comment: 1) try ls -la    and look where symlink goes, is it right way?
2) try to change CHOD to storage folder
3) try to remove symlink, and recreate it manually 'ln -s /path/to/laravel/storage/app/public /path/to/public/storage'

Answer (score 1):

**In config/filesystems.php, you could do this... change the root element in public**

*Note : instead of upload you can use your folder name*

```
'disks' => [
   'public' => [
       'driver' => 'local',
       'root'   => public_path() . '/uploads',
       'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
       'visibility' => 'public',
    ]
]
```

*and you can access it by*

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('uploaded_imgs', $request->file('my_file'));
```

**or**

```
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path(),
    ],
    'uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path() . '/uploads',
    ],
]
```

*Then use it :*

```
Storage::disk('uploads')->put('filename', $file_content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('uploaded_imgs', $request->file('my_file'));
```

hopefully it will work.

Comment: they are uploading the file without issue and to a path that is what the `public` disk covers, assuming the default configuration for the `public `disk

Answer (score 0):

When you run `php artisan storage:link` command, Laravel generates a "storage" symlink under "public" folder which directs to `/storage/app/public` so your code is correct.

There is no `public/storage` directory, its a symlink which directs to `/storage/app/public` which is where your `uploaded_imgs` folder has been generated.

`public/storage => /storage/app/public`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to upload a file:

```
$file = $request->file('my_file');
$fileNameWithoutExtension = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);

$path = "public/uploaded_imgs/" + $fileNameWithoutExtension +"."+$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

Storage::disk('local')->put($path, file_get_contents($file), 'public');
```

Comment: they are uploading the file without issue and to a path that is what the `public` disk covers, assuming the default configuration for the `public `disk